# Toggling between JPanels (hide/show)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have two JPanels that sit on top of one another. The 'top' panel holds many widgets (JButtons, JTextFields, etc.). One of the buttons will initiate an action to display a number of images.

These images are displayed on the other JPanel. So, when this button is clicked, I want to hide the control panel and display the images panel. Sounds pretty simple.

Here is the code (I've omitted a lot of stuff that I don't think is relevant). In the constructor, if I switch which panel is visible when the app launches, it looks fine either way. When I click the button, I should go from my dark gray control panel to my blue images panel. Except that what happens is my dark gray control panel becomes an empty white panel. Any ideas?

```
public GUI() {

   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   ...
   JPanel imagesPanel = new ImagesPanel();
   imagesPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
   imagesPanel.setVisible(false);
   frame.getContentPane().add(imagesPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

   // make a JPanel to hold all of the buttons and text fields
   JPanel imagesPanel = new ImagesPanel();
   controlPanel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
   controlPanel.setVisible(true);
   frame.getContentPane().add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   ...

    JButton btnDisplayImages = new JButton("Display Images");
    btnDisplayImages.setPreferredSize(standardButtonSize);
    btnDisplayImages.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            imagesPanel.setVisible(true);
            controlPanel.setVisible(false);
            frame.repaint();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });   
    // button added to control panel

    ...
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, this sounds like a good use-case for a CardLayout. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Comment: Didn't know about that one. Let me look into it. Thanks!

Comment: and I believe that you were seeing a white panel because you inserted two objects into the `Borderlayout.CENTER` section. The second panel you added replaced the first panel you added. You then made the second non-visible in your `actionPerformed()` method.

Comment: Expanded my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CardLayout. (docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

```
final String IMAGES_PANEL = "Images Panel";
final String CONTROL_PANEL = "Control Panel";
CardLayout cardLayout;
JPanel cards;

//Where the components controlled by the CardLayout are initialized:
//Create the "cards".
JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
...
JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
...

//Create the panel that contains the "cards".
cardLayout = new CardLayout();
cards = new JPanel(cardLayout);
cards.add(card1, IMAGES_PANEL);
cards.add(card2, CONTROL_PANEL);
...
//Show images panel
cardLayout.show(cards,IMAGES_PANEL);
...
//Show control panel
cardLayout.show(cards, CONTROL_PANEL);
```